# Cannot forward declare a typedef?

Tags: c, struct, typedef, forward-declaration

I am learning C by programming a chess application and I have a problem with circular references. My linkedList.h looks like this:

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H
#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif  /* LINKEDLIST_H */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include "squares.h"

typedef struct node {
tSquare c;
struct node * next;
} node_square;



void createEmptyList(node_square* n);
int isEmptyList(node_square* n);
int insertAtBeginning(node_square** n, tSquare c); 
void print_list(node_square * head);
```

And in my squares.h I want to include the linkedList.h functionality so that I can return a linked list of squares threatened by one of the sides (black or white):

```
#ifndef SQUARES_H
#define SQUARES_H
#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif  /* SQUARES_H */

typedef struct {
    int file;
    int rank;
} tSquare;

node_square* listOfThreatenedSquares(tColor color); <--- undefined types in compilation time
```

I've read that what I should use is forward referencing; I am trying to use it so that in the squares.h file I can use types node_square and tColor (which is defined in another file called pieces.h) but no matter how I declare the types, it just isn't working. I guess it's something like

`typedef struct node_square node_square;
typedef struct tColor tColor;`

in the squares.h. Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I guess it's something like
>
> ```
> typedef struct node_square node_square;
> typedef struct tColor tColor;
> ```

This is right - that is indeed a way to forward-declare `node_square` and `tColor`. However, forward-declared types are considered *incomplete*, so you need to follow one rule when using them: you cannot declare variables, arrays, struct members, or function parameters of the forward-declared type itself; only pointers (or pointers to pointers, pointers to pointers to pointers, etc.) are allowed.

This will compile:

```
node_square* listOfThreatenedSquares(tColor *color);
```

If you do not wish to use pointers for some reason, you can include the corresponding header to provide the compiler with the actual declaration of the class.

Comment: The reason why it didn't work is that I wasn't using the same declaration as in the original header file. Something to be very meticulous with. Danke schön.